# How to set static IP address on Ubuntu server 22.04 with GUI?

Tags: networking, 22.04

This is a virtual machine in VMWare ESXi 6.5. I have the GUI installed on the VM OS. I see that I should be using (according to other posts) Settings->Network. As you can see there is nothing there to set IP:

[image]

Why? How does one set network settings in this environment?

Comment: Start with the Network Settings in the Host VM application (VMWare ESXi 6.5). Not the Host OS network settings. Not the Guest OS network settings.